# Como usar jQuery.validation em Checkboxes geradas por jQuery.repeater?

Tags: jquery, laravel

Estou a usar DubFriend/jquery.repeater para repetir alguns campos num formulário, proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation para exportar regras de validação de Laravel, e jQuery.validation para as validar.

Checkboxes processadas pelo jquery.repeater, recebem sempre um [] depois do nome.

O campo em questão é o seguinte:

```
<input name="ep_is_default" type="checkbox">
```

Após o Repeater ser inicializado o campo fica com esta formatação:

```
<input name="group-prof_entities[0][ep_is_default][]" type="checkbox">
```

A regra espera um campo com este nome:

```
group-prof_entities[*][ep_is_default]
```

A diferença é o [] no nome.

Alguma ideia em como resolver este problema?

Tentei:
 - Manualmente apagar "[]" e a regra funcionou.
 - Criar uma função para fazer isto automaticamente e chama-la na inicialização do Repeater, na duplicação de elementos e na eliminação de cópias.

Mas falha da eliminação de elementos porque os indexes são recalculados e "[]" reinserido no nome das checkboxes.

Obrigado.

Comment: Pedro, esse é o [pt.so], então faça a pergunta em português, por favor.

Comment: Traduzido, obrigado